Strange wiring configuration in 3-way switches
For the second time in a week I have come across confusing wiring for a 3-way light switch layout.  I dove into trying to understand 3-way wiring options after a previous post about them, so I thought I had a good handle on it.  But, alas, I am confused again.
Here is what I am working with:

15A switches in a 15A circuit

One switch at the bottom of the stairs (I’ll call this “bottom box”) and one switch at the top of the stairs (I’ll call this “top box”).  Both switches control two lights (one at the bottom, one at the top)

There are several wires coming into top box.  Romex 14/3 with hot on R (not connected, marked with a red arrow in pic) and B (connected with a wire nut to several other B wires, including a pigtail to a 2nd switch in the same box that controls exterior light), and W (no current).  There is a 14/2 as well (circled red in the pic), with the W tied in the box to other neutrals and the B carrying power away from the switch.  With all wires disconnected in top box, I have power on R (red arrow) and nothing on that Romex’s  W, or on the 14/2’s black.  There are other 14/2s in top box, but they don’t have anything to do with the 3 way.  Here is a pic of the box 

With all wires disconnected at bottom box as well, I have power on BOTH B and R and nothing on W.

There are no tape/paint markings on any wire, so that’s obviously my first hurdle.

I also made the mistake of not taking pictures before I removed the old switches (yes, I know…lesson learned)


I can get the lights to turn on and turn off using certain configurations. However, I know they’re not correct because the functionality of the switches isn’t right. Not sure how to describe the problem exactly, but essentially each switch only works when the other switch has the lights on.
Here are the scenarios I’ve encountered:

When the top box’s W/R are energized light is off then bottom box’s B/W/R all energized…but bottom button doesn’t turn anything off or on
When the top box’s B/W/R are energized light is on then bottom box’s B/W/R all energized…but bottom button doesn’t turn turn light off and on; however, when bottom button turns light off then only B/W are energized

For the life of me, I cannot picture what is happening here and how to wire it.   I know the basics of 3-way switches (travelers, etc.).  But this is baffling me.  Anyone have recommendations or wiring diagrams that could help me picture this?

Are all hots on only one circuit so turning one breaker off cuts all power in all hot in both boxes? What kind of test equipment do you have?

In the top box, yes there is only one circuit from the breaker.  The bottom box has multiple circuits…the previous person did that, with no warning I might add.  Thank goodness I know to check.  However, they are completely separate circuits (other than their grounds being tied together).  I’m just using a noncontact voltage tester at the moment.  I’m not super handy with a multimeter, but I’m trying to learn.

The box pictured has four cables and two switches, right? One switch is a 3-way and with another 3-way at the bottom controls the two lights on the stairway, right? The other switch controls a different light, right?

If the hots from the different breakers are somewhere connected together, you could have a complicated mess.  PROBABLY the line hot and its associated neutral ( B and W in the same cable) for the stairs lights enters in either the top box or the bottom box. (Less likely is that the line hot and its neutral enters in one of the boxes for the lights). I think the first thing is to identify the line hot and its neutral where it enters the circuit. The line hot will be B and its neutral W in the same /2 cable with a bare G.

Which of the two switches (right or left in the picture) controls the lights on the stairs?

Jim Stewart—the switch on the right of the picture (with R attached) is the 3 way.  The one on the left controls a different light.  As for the cables in the box there are 4 total cables.  There is a 14/3 that controls the 3 way, but the B from that cable gets tied into the bundle of black cables in the middle of the box.  The 14/2 that is circled is the one that carries power away from the switch (I know it carries it away because it is not hot when the power is on.

As for the circuits being tied together, while I am not 100% certain, I don’t think that is what I have here.  I think they are separate circuits.

Is it a single-breaker or a double-breaker/handle-tied pair of breakers that turns off the 3-way power (i.e., both R and B)?

AFIK the normal way this is set up the /3 cable connects the two 3-way switches with the R and the B travelers and the W the neutral. It appears to me your R is attached to the common!? So I think this is wrong. I repeat, you need to identify which /2 cable is the line hot. It would be the B in one of the /2 cables and it would be the only wire which if disconnectied would interrupt power to all other wires except itself. If you find it in the upper box, then it should be connected to the common of the switch (dark screw IIRC).

That’s what is so confusing to me.  The only two wires coming into the box with power are the R in the 14/3 and the B in the 14/3.  However, that B was tied together with other blacks and not connected to the 3 way switch in the original configuration (no jumper from one switch to another).  I’m willing to explore if the original configuration was incorrect though.  How would I be able to figure out which wire is line hot vs which is a traveler?

Take a picture and then disconnect the bundle of black wires. With the power back only one of the black wires should be hot (live) and all other wires should be unpowered, including all wires associated with this circuit in the other switch box. That B should be the line hot and should be in a /2 cable with a W and a gnd. But note that it is possible that the line hot enters in the other switch box. You need to show  pic of the backs of the two switches so we can see the connections.

As for the group of B wires tied together, the one that is powered is part of the 14/3 that also has the R with power. So, I think that means the power is coming in from the light on both the B and the R in the top box, as well as on the B and R in the bottom box. But, since I didn’t take a pic before disconnecting the old switches (lesson learned) I’m not sure which is the hot and which is the traveler (I’m banking on the W being the other traveler in both boxes since no power comes into either box on W). Is there a way to determine which is common/hot between the B and R wires? A multimeter?

Did this combination of two 3-way switches function properly before you started working on it? Opening up the ceiling boxes is likely going to be necessay to determine what the arrangement is, but working in ceiling boxes on a ladder on stairs is difficult and risky. Are the lights in the ceiling or on the wall? What boxes have ends of the /3 cable?
